# How to refactor {{link-to}} helper into a function that can be used in transitionTo?

Tags: ember.js

I currently use a {{link-to}} helper that was written by someone else to explicitly state the query params to pass to the next route and strip out others that are not stated. It looks like this:

```
//link-to example

{{#link-to 'route' (explicit-query-params fromDate=thisDate toDate=thisDate)} Link Text {{/link-to}}

//the helper

import {helper} from '@ember/component/helper';
import Object from '@ember/object';
import {assign} from '@ember/polyfills';

export function explicitQueryParams(params, hash) {
  let values = assign({}, hash);
  values._explicitQueryParams = true;

  return Object.create({
    isQueryParams: true,
    values,
  });
}

export default helper(explicitQueryParams);

// supporting method in router.js

const Router = EmberRouter.extend({
  _hydrateUnsuppliedQueryParams(state, queryParams) {
      if (queryParams._explicitQueryParams) {
        delete queryParams._explicitQueryParams;

        return queryParams;
      }
      return this._super(state, queryParams);
    },

});
```

I've recently had a use case where I need to apply the same logic to a `transitionTo()` that is being used to redirect users from a route based on their access:

```
 beforeModel() {
    if (auth) {
      this.transitionTo('route')
    } else {
      this.transitionTo('access-denied-route')
    }
},
```

I am really struggling to see how I can refactor what I have in the handlebars helper to a re-usable function in the `transitionTo()` segment. I'm even unsure if `transitionTo()` forwards the same arguments as `{{link-to}}` or if I will have to fetch the queryParams somehow from a different location.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well first off, tapping into private methods like `_hydrateUnsuppliedQueryParams` is risky. It will make upgrading more difficult. Most people use `resetController` to clear stick query params. You could also explicitly clear the default values by passing empty values on the transition.

But, ill bite because this can be fun to figure out :) Check this [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/80d1b9edac21cfd75e84b8c63125d8cb?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C&route=%2Ftest%3Ffoo%3DredirectFoo) that does what you're wanting.

If you work from the beginning in the `transitionTo` case, we can see that in the [router.js](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/d6352a54c068354da93bcb26a5df4c7ef9153ea7/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/router.js#L380) implementation:

```
transitionTo(...args) {
    let queryParams;
    let arg = args[0];
    if (resemblesURL(arg)) {
      return this._doURLTransition('transitionTo', arg);
    }

    let possibleQueryParams = args[args.length - 1];
    if (possibleQueryParams && possibleQueryParams.hasOwnProperty('queryParams')) {
      queryParams = args.pop().queryParams;
    } else {
      queryParams = {};
    }

    let targetRouteName = args.shift();
    return this._doTransition(targetRouteName, args, queryParams);
  }
```

So, if the last argument is an object with a query params obj, that's going directly into `_doTransition`, which ultimately calls:

```
_prepareQueryParams(targetRouteName, models, queryParams, _fromRouterService) {
    let state = calculatePostTransitionState(this, targetRouteName, models);
    this._hydrateUnsuppliedQueryParams(state, queryParams, _fromRouterService);
    this._serializeQueryParams(state.handlerInfos, queryParams);

    if (!_fromRouterService) {
      this._pruneDefaultQueryParamValues(state.handlerInfos, queryParams);
    }
}
```

which has the `_hydrateUnsuppliedQueryParams` function. So, to make this all work, you can't share the function directly from the `helper` you've created. Rather, just add `_explicitQueryParams: true` to your query params. Job done :)
The `link-to` version is different. The query params use

```
let queryParams = get(this, 'queryParams.values');
```

since the `link-to` component can take a variable number of dynamic segments and there needs to be some way to distinguish between the passed dynamic segments, a passed model, and query params.

Comment: That's an incredible answer, thank you for your time and making a twiddle. As a new developer it never occurs to me look at what the framework providers do - I take them for granted. Thank you also for the note about `resetController`. Checking the docs I can see how this also provides a solution